# Not able to access parentWidget()

Tags: c++, desktop-application, signals-slots, qt5.10

I am working on a camera project. In this i have created a Window type QT Widget application. I have also added 2 separate dialog window classes which are supposed to access the functions in the `MainWindow` class. One of the dialog class is able to access the functions from the main class using connect function and putting `parentWidget()` calue for `QObject *context` parameter. The dialog class is called on camera button using non modal method :

```
void MainWindow::on_addCamera_Button_clicked()
{
    flag1 = 1;
    if(imageFilename != ""){
        c++;
        camera = new CameraDialog(this);
        camera->show();
        img2.copyTo(im);
        img2.copyTo(img);
        img2.copyTo(img1);
        imshow("Map",img1);
        setMouseCallback("Map", onMouseClick, &p);
        connect(timer_ossm, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(gui_update_Original_Video()));
        connect(timer_ossm, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(gui_update_Image_Coordinate()));
        }
    else {
        QMessageBox::warning(this,"..",(QString)"Enter Image!");
    }
}
```

And the connect statements that work fine in `CameraDialog` class are :

```
CameraDialog::CameraDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::CameraDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->pushButton_Done->setCheckable(true);
    cout<<parentWidget()<<endl;
    connect(ui->pushButton_Done,SIGNAL(clicked()),parentWidget(),SLOT(clearVal()));
    connect(ui->pushButton_Done,SIGNAL(clicked()),parentWidget(),SLOT(updateFlag()));
    connect(ui->pushButton_Done, SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(close()));
    connect(ui->pushButton_Apply,SIGNAL(clicked()),parentWidget(),SLOT(updateImage());
    connect(ui->pushButton_Cancel,SIGNAL(clicked()),parentWidget(),SLOT(clearVal()));
}
```

But when I try the same thing for another class for a different dialog window (which accessed using the same non modal approach)it show that there is no value for `parentWidget()`, i.e, it shows value 0 when trying to print value of `parentWidget()`. Because of this the same connect functions in the 1st dialog class(`CameraDialog`) are not working. How do I solve this issue so that the second class can also access the functions in the `MainWindow` class?

Thanks!

Comment: is your code give any error about signal and slots?

Comment: @MohammadrezaPanahi, yes I get this message on my application output when I try to open my second dialog box   `QObject::connect: Cannot connect QPushButton::clicked() to (null)::clearVal()`  
`QObject::connect: Cannot connect QPushButton::clicked() to (null)::updateFlag()`

Comment: whats exactly, error message?

Comment: your source code works fine, when do you get this error?

Comment: No. My program stops unexpectedly. I believe the error is because the second dialog class is not able to use the MainWindow class as parentWidget(). I also tried setparent() method for the second dialog class's object, but it didn't work.

Comment: do you using `    camera->setWindowFlags( Qt::Window);
    camera->setWindowModality( Qt::ApplicationModal );` before show dialog?

Comment: No.Is this supposed to allow the second dialog class to access the MainWindow functions using connect function?

Comment: send your main windows code and dialog code where got error...

Comment: if its long, can you email that? just that part of the code that makes error

Comment: dont need help?

Comment: @MohammadrezaPanahi, I tried your statements `camera->setWindowFlags( Qt::Window); camera->setWindowModality( Qt::ApplicationModal );` For the first dialog class and now my first dialog window is also not working. How do I undo this. Also, I can only send screen shots of the program as my teammates are not allowing to send code.

Comment: ok, take screen shot then upload it and send me its link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174499/discussion-between-mohammadreza-panahi-and-aditya).